# Is there a function that can sort my integer array values from smallest to largest?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

If I had a array containing integers, whats the best way to sort them from smallest to greatest?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very easy:

```
int[] intarray;
// ...
Arrays.sort(intarray);
```

If you have a List instead:

```
List<Integer> numbers;
// ...
Collections.sort(numbers);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] x= new int[] {1,2,3,4,0,-3};

Arrays.sort(x);

for(int temp: x) {
    System.out.println( temp);
}
```

Comment: Why not just `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));`?

Comment: I am just showing how this stud can do print

Comment: And I just showed you how to do it properly. And what's `i` declared for?

Comment: Frankly , even this student is not supposed to use Arrays.sort ,he has to learn how to implement sorting by himself and displaying things until he become expert. Anyway, thank you for your marvelous lecture

Comment: @DanHunex - Stud?  Really?  Where's the evidence?  :-)

Comment: @Saucymeatman so why dont you see the Java API, I mean the java API has everything you needed. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html